# How to loop over an array using PostgreSQL JSON functions

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgreSQL database with an `entities` table with a `permissions` column of type `jsonb`. `permissions` is an array of permissions. Each permission has an array of `principals` and an `operation`. The actual JSON of the `permissions` column for a particular entity could look like for example like this:

```
[
  {
    "principals": [
      "Administrators",
      "Users"
    ],
    "operation": "read"
  },
  {
    "principals": [
      "Administrators"
    ],
    "operation": "write"
  }
]
```

Now I want to retrieve all entities where either "Editors" or "Guests" have "read" permission. But the only syntax I can come up with is the one below where I query only the *first* permission (index=0) of the entities:

```sql
SELECT * FROM entities WHERE permissions->0->'principals' ?| array['Editors', 'Guests'] and permissions->0->>'operation' = 'read'
```

How do I modify this query to comprise *all* the permissions of an entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, this might work for you:

```
select * from entities e
where exists(select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(e.permissions) r
        where (r->'principals' ?| array['Users', 'Editors']) and r->>'operation' = 'read')
```